# Including class files in gradle build script

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, build.gradle

I have useful java class files from a old project on my computer and would like to include them in a build.gradle script for a new project.  I also am using a library off the Maven repository and a jar file on my computer. I'm only have problem with including the classes and no problem with either of the others. Here is the dependency block.

```
dependencies {
compile 'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.14' //works
compile files('../lib/opencv-320.jar') //works
compile files('../oldProject/com')  } //seems ok in IntelliJ, but won't compile
```

By including the oldProject/com in this way IntelliJ is able to see the dependency and recognize the class.  However, when proceeding to run the app, here is the error that suggests the package "util" and class "MultiArray" in oldProject/com are not being seen by the Kotlin compiler.

```
Information: Kotlin: kotlinc -jvm 1.2.21 (JRE 1.80_71-b15)
Error:(3,8) Kotlin: Unresolved reference util
Error:(18,17) Kotlin: Unresolved reference MultiArray
```

Here is the include line in the top level settings.gradle file

```
include ('../oldProject/com')
```

Answer (score 0):

`com` is your top-level package and not the directory root. You have to add the dependency

```
 compile files('../oldProject')
```

IntelliJ can detect directory prefixes, but Gradle does not do that.